# Conditional variables in Makefile

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, make

I am trying to compile source code in various ways. For example, suppose I want to compile a fortran program with source code `main.f90`, `file1.f90`, and `file2.f90` as inputs. To generate `hello.exe`, I would simply do

```
FC=gfortran
EXE=hello.exe
OBJS=file1.o file2.o
FFLAGS=

$(EXE): $(OBJS)
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) main.f90 $(OBJS) -o $(EXE)

file1.o: file1.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c file1.f90

file2.o: file2.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c file2.f90

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Now, suppose I want to make various versions of this and compare output. I would like to make a `hello_O2.exe` which uses the `-O2` compilation flag, a `hello_O3.exe` version with a `-O3` flag, and even compile with different compilers. I would like a `hello_intel_O2.exe` which uses the `-O2` flag as well as uses the `ifort` intel compiler, for example.

Ideally, I would like to specify `make intelO3` to use the `ifort` compiler and `-O3` flag which and would generate the `hello_intel_O3.exe` executable. If I specify `make all` it would create the `hello_O2.exe`, `hello_O3.exe`, `hello_intel_O2.exe`, and `hello_intel_O3.exe` binaries, each with the correct compiler and optimization levels.

How can this be achieved in this minimal example? My actual Makefile is ~120 lines right now and uses many variables which I change each time I want to build for a different version.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override any variables set in the makefile when you 
give them as arguments to the make command.  So eg:

```
#!/bin/make
FC=gfortran
EXE=hello$(SUFFIX).exe
OBJS=file1.o file2.o
FFLAGS=

default: $(EXE)

intelO3:
        $(MAKE) FC=ifort FFLAGS=-O3 SUFFIX=_intel_O3
all:
        $(MAKE) FFLAGS=-O2 SUFFIX=_O2
        $(MAKE) FFLAGS=-O3 SUFFIX=_O3
        $(MAKE) FC=ifort FFLAGS=-O3 SUFFIX=_intel_O3

... rest of makefile
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest that, just as you want multiple different copies of the `.exe` program file, you also maintain multiple copies of the `.o` files.
   Something like this:

   ```
   file1_gfortran.o: file1.f90
           gfortran $(FFLAGS) -c file1.f90 -o file1_gfortran.o

   file2_gfortran.o: file2.f90
           gfortran $(FFLAGS) -c file2.f90 -o file2_gfortran.o

   file1_ifort.o:    file1.f90
           ifort    $(FFLAGS) -c file1.f90 -o file1_ifort.o

   file2_ifort.o:    file2.f90
           ifort    $(FFLAGS) -c file2.f90 -o file2_ifort.o
   ```

   otherwise you will need to recompile *every* `.f90` file
   any time you modify any of them. 
   (This will get to be significant when you have `file3.f90`, `file4.f90`, etc...)

   - You may be able to eliminate some of the verbose redundancy;
     e.g., use `-o $<`.  See also paragraph 5, below.
   - You may need to have two different copies of `FFLAGS`,
     if there’s more there than just the `-On` flag.
   - I guess you will want to define `OBJS=file1_$(FC).o file2_$(FC).o`.
2. Rather than just have a list of commands, I suggest that you explicitly identify all the target files that you (might) want to produce; e.g.,

   ```
   hello.exe:
           $(MAKE)

   hello_O2.exe:
           $(MAKE)          FFLAGS=-O2 SUFFIX=_O2

   hello_O3.exe:
           $(MAKE)          FFLAGS=-O3 SUFFIX=_O3

   hello_intel.exe:
           $(MAKE) FC=ifort            SUFFIX=_intel

   hello_intel_O2.exe:
           $(MAKE) FC=ifort FFLAGS=-O2 SUFFIX=_intel_O2

   hello_intel_O3.exe:
           $(MAKE) FC=ifort FFLAGS=-O3 SUFFIX=_intel_O3
   ```

   so then you can say

   ```
   intelO3: hello_intel_O3.exe
   ```

   without having to enter the `$(MAKE) FC=ifort FFLAGS=-O3 SUFFIX=_intel_O3`
   command twice.  Then, obviously, you would say:

   ```
   all: hello.exe hello_O2.exe hello_O3.exe hello_intel.exe hello_intel_O2.exe hello_intel_O3.exe
   ```
3. Actually, the above would probably work better with pseudo-targets:

   ```
   all: gf gfO2 gfO3 intel intelO2 intelO3

   gf:
           $(MAKE) FC=gfortran

   gfO2:
           $(MAKE) FC=gfortran FFLAGS=-O2 SUFFIX=_O2

   gfO3:
           $(MAKE) FC=gfortran FFLAGS=-O3 SUFFIX=_O3

   intel:
           $(MAKE) FC=ifort               SUFFIX=_intel

   intelO2:
           $(MAKE) FC=ifort    FFLAGS=-O2 SUFFIX=_intel_O2

   intelO3:
           $(MAKE) FC=ifort    FFLAGS=-O3 SUFFIX=_intel_O3
   ```
4. And then you might be able to collapse the last six stanzas above to *something like* this:

   ```
   gf gfO2 gfO3 intel intelO2 intelO3:
           case $< in (gf*) compiler=gfortran; suffix="";; \
                      (in*) compiler=ifort; suffix="_intel";; esac; \
           case $< in (*O2) flags="-O2"; suffix="${suffix}_O2";; \
                      (*O3) flags="-O3"; suffix="${suffix}_O3";; esac; \
           $(MAKE) FC="$compiler" FFLAGS="$flags" SUFFIX="$suffix"
   ```

   Note that this is a multi-line shell command
   (continued by backslashes at the ends of lines). 
   You need this if you want to set a shell variable in one line
   and use it in the next; the default behavior of `make`
   is to spawn a separate shell process for each command line,
   thus losing local side-effects like working directory (`cd`)
   and shell variables.
5. Going back to the first paragraph: you may be able to simplify that to

   ```
   file1_gfortran.o file1_ifort.o: file1.f90
           case $< in (_gf*) compiler=gfortran;; \
                      (_if*) compiler=ifort;; esac; \
           "$compiler" $(FFLAGS) -c file1.f90 -o $<

   file2_gfortran.o file2_ifort.o: file2.f90
           case $< in (_gf*) compiler=gfortran;; \
                      (_if*) compiler=ifort;; esac; \
           "$compiler" $(FFLAGS) -c file2.f90 -o $<
   ```

   and I suspect that you can combine the above into a single stanza
   (starting with something like `X_gfortran.o X_ifort.o: X.f90`),
   but I can't remember how.

Caveat: I haven’t tested any of this.